# Accessing different servers with same domain name

Tags: linux, proxy, tomcat, domain

I have a Linux Server `(Ser1)` on which an application is running on Apache and tomcat using proxy. This server has a registered domain name `abc.web.example`. Because of traffic, company has taken another Linux Server `(Ser2)` (with no domain name).

What I want is, whenever there is a hit on `abc.web.example` it should access the same server. But when there is a hit on `abc.web.example/panda` the request should be redirect to another server `(Ser2)`

Re-paraphrasing:

```
Ser1  abc.web.example    IP: 10.201.x.x  
Ser2  No domain name     IP: 10.201.y.z
```

Note: `Ser2` should be accessed by url `abc.web.example/panda`

Comment: I don't meant to be rude, but it seems according to the blurry explanation you gave that you don't really understand nor master your topic. Be careful when you will try the answer (which seems OK)

Comment: If I had mastered it then why would I ask it here. Asking something will never means it will comprehend everyone's intellect. By the way thanks for your comment.

Comment: You will have less problems if you gave a name to the second one, like `ser2.web.example` even if it resolves only locally, so that configuration at `ser1` will be simpler. You just need proxying at the HTTP level.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I didn't give domain name not to make any confusion as for this server there is no domain name. Yes, I can give ser2.web.example that could be locally resolve.

Comment: I do not see how not giving the name helps in not confusing things. On the opposite I believe that without a name it makes things less clear. Also the proxying will be more complicated, as webservers needs hostnames and not just IP addresses because multiple websites could be installed on the same IP.

Answer (score 1):

As an architectural solution, which is very dependent of the particular application you've got, I'd suggest you consider something like this:

1. Set up DNS so that your canonical website name points to both servers (round robin, if you have the choice).
2. Set up Tomcat on both servers, sharing the same data source.
3. Set up Apache on both servers with a load balancing split between the local Tomcat and overflow to the other. If you can't do that, set it up to send `/panda` to one and everything else to the other.

This will allow you to mediate requests using both servers, even if only one of them is able to service the actual response.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure `apache` to proxy the request to `Ser2`:

`ProxyPass "/panda" "http://ser2.web.com"`

Or if `Ser2` has no domain name, you can proxy to the `IP`:

`ProxyPass "/panda" "http://10.201.y.z"`

Comment: I have already tried that. It is redirecting to the same server (Ser1). Also, I am already using ProxyPass to redirect it to tomcat. 

As: "ProxyPass /  http://localhost:8080/"

Comment: Ordering is important: `ProxyPass / localhost:8080/` proxies everything that matches `/` (that is, all URIs) to tomcat, including `/panda`. First match wins. So you must place `ProxyPass "/panda" ...` **before** `ProxyPass / ...`.